# Replace switch with design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Here is my class diagram
[image]

I also have an enum for all the fields in the CameraControl base class.

In the implementation of the GetCommand() in the PelcoDCommand class, I have a switch statement that returns the command based on the enum.

The switch statement consists of 18 case (one for each enum). For example,

```
public override byte[] GetCommand(PelcoDCommands command)
{
  switch(command)
  {
    case PelcoDCommands.Stop:
      return Stop;
    case PelcoDCommands.PanUp:
      return PanUp;
    case PelcoDCommands.PanDown:
      return PanDown;
                .........
  }
}
```

Can anyone point me to a proper pattern to replace the switch statement? And if anyone has a guide to a better implementation of the classes?

## **Edit**

All the fields of the Abstract class are byte arrays.

Here is the PelcoDCommands enum:

```
public enum PelcoDCommands { PanUp, PanDown, TiltLeft, TiltRight, PanTiltUpright, PanTiltUpleft, PanTiltDownRight, PanTiltDownLeft, ZoomIn, ZoomOut, FocusNear, FocusFar, EnableThermal, DisableThermal, BlackHot, WhiteHot, SetZoomSpeed, Stop }
```

I'm also working on implementing Dictionary CommandValue that I will use with linq to return the correct value as follows:

public override byte[] GetCommand(PelcoDCommands command)
    {

```
    SetCommandChecksum();
    var cmd = CommandValue.Where(x => x.Key == command);
    return **/*still working on it*/**;
}
```

Where CommandValue is Dictionary and is set as follows:

```
Dictionary<PelcoDCommands, byte[]> CommandValue = new Dictionary<PelcoDCommands, byte[]>();
CommandValue.Add(PelcoDCommands.Stop, Stop);
CommandValue.Add(PelcoDCommands.PanUp, PanUp);
CommandValue.Add(PelcoDCommands.PanDown, PanDown);
CommandValue.Add(PelcoDCommands.TiltLeft, TiltLeft);
CommandValue.Add(PelcoDCommands.TiltRight, TiltRight);
```

I just relized that I'm using the PelcoDCommands enum for the GetCommand() abstract method declaration which will not work because there will be other classes that inherit from CameraControl class.

Comment: What have you tried? Is a custom attribute on the enum members an option? Or a dictionary where you register pairs? What does the `Stop` field contain? A design pattern an sich is unlikely to help here.

Comment: The diagram leaves one to guess, unfortunately. `GetCommand` appears to be abstract but its parameter is of type `PelcoDCommands`? If so, surely you'll only ever have one concrete class derived from it?

Comment: I have updated the post. @ Damien_The_Unbeliever  I just realized what you mean and I have to modify the base class.

Comment: Should I change the implementation from an abstract class to Interface?

Comment: What's your `CommandValue` collection declare on your edit question? In my opinion, why don't you use `Stop`,`PanUp`  instead of  use `GetCommand` method  directly,because they only are fieds from base class.

Comment: CommandValue is the dictionary I'm testing with to implement the strategy pattern. I have updated the edit

Comment: @D-Shih the PelcoDCommands.PanUp is an enum while PanUp is a byte array that consists of the data I want to use. Is that what you are asking or did I understand incorrectly?

Comment: Looks like a Strategy pattern to me

Comment: @AndrewK  I am in the process of implementing the Strategy pattern as you see but is there something more suited for this?

Comment: I don't fully understand what is this dictionary for. I would make GetCommand method return an instance of IPelcoDCommand which would be a concrete command you want to execute. Otherwise the dictionary should be Dictionary<PelcoDCommands, IPelcoDCommand>.

Comment: @David what exactly are you trying to achieve? The Strategy pattern is only relevant if you feel that both choosing a strategy and using that strategy is too much responsibility for one class. Otherwise, a switch statement is just fine. Looking at the signature of `GetCommand()`, it looks like a dumb mapper -- the strategy/command has already been decided elsewhere and is not executed here. Why the need for a pattern?

Comment: @guillaume31 I want to make the code more OOP. The GetCommand() returns one of the byte arrays that corresponds with the command that I sent after reflecting values like speed and calculating checksums. My original implementation used GetCommand() as a wrapper for a Switch statement. Now I'm looking for a better more modular way to do this.

Comment: @AndrewK If I understand you correctly, you are saying to create a class for each one of the 18 commands. And make the GetCommand() return an instance of the class instead of a byte array? Can you give me a sample code?

Comment: Basically yes. Each command is a strategy actually and GetCommand method is just defining a strategy. All strategies should implement one interface, so that the client code stays the same no matter which strategy is picked up. For examples reach to https://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern or https://dotnetfreakblog.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/strategy-design-pattern-using-c/ or https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776819/Strategy-Pattern-Csharp

Comment: @AndrewK isn't that a little overkill for a 3 LOC method that basically does a dictionary lookup and returns a value? I agree that the `byte[]` could be wrapped into something more relevantly typed, but the whole Strategy thing...

Comment: That would be more OOP, wouldn't it? The goal is not just to replace the command lookup. You are going to do something with this value, right? Some action, different for each command. So the purpose is to get this action right away, moving the camera in your case. So the output of GetCommand should be an instance of a strategy that will have a method Execute() which will move the camera properly.